# preg_replace, negate regex pattern

Tags: regex, preg-replace, negate

This is my pattern which i want to negate:

```
[\+\-][0-9\.]+
```

These are sample rows:

```
Stephane Robert (+1.5 Sets)
Stephane Robert (-1.5 Sets)
Philipp Kohlschreiber
Philipp Kohlschreiber (-1.5 Sets)
Philipp Kohlschreiber (+1.5 Sets)
Player Names (n)
Another Player-Player
```

I want to strip all but the numbers, matching the pattern, i.e. i want only the positive or negative float number.

```
+1.5
-1.5
-1.5
+1.5
```

I'm using php and preg_replace.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this. This will also remove other lines which doesn't have the desired value.

```
(?=.*[+-]\d+\.\d+).*([+-]\d+\.\d+).*|(.*)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/kTKMyP/1)

> PHP Code sample

```
$re = '/(?=.*[+-]\d+\.\d+).*([+-]\d+\.\d+).*|(.*)/m';
    $str = 'Stephane Robert (+1.5 Sets)
    Stephane Robert (-1.5 Sets)
    Philipp Kohlschreiber
    Philipp Kohlschreiber (-1.5 Sets)
    Philipp Kohlschreiber (+1.5 Sets)
    Player Names (n)
    Another Player-Player';
    $subst = '\\1';

    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

    echo $result;
```

Comment: Why downvoted ? would like to know the reason to enhance the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find strings that match your pattern, just use `preg_match()` instead of `preg_replace()`.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: And `preg_match` won't do the job since there are multiple values to extract.

Comment: Useful version, thanks, but i have to use preg_replace for some reason.